# Regex validation Allow only Character and space in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

hello every one i need a validation that can only validate to character and white space.. no mater how much space and character in text-box

i use this regexp validation below. but its only allow one space between two words but don`t allow the third space for third word.

([A-Za-z])+( [A-Za-z]+)

how to allow only characters and spaces in Regexp Validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
([A-Za-z])+( [A-Za-z]+)*
                       ^^ here
```

`*` means to repeat the group zero or more times. If you need it to be one or more times, then use `+`. Another thing you can use `[ ]+` instead of space to handle one or more consecutive spaces.

Also, if you need, you can use anchor `^` and `$` around your regex. Like `^...regex...$`

Comment: it`s all my fault how much i am stupid i totally forgot the regex validation syntax but Thanks for explaining. it`s working

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

`^([\sA-Za-z]+)$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mQ0jN4

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Regex.IsMatch(inputToValidate, @"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$")
```